# For loop overiding the previous result

Tags: python

Count the number of trailing 0s in factorial of a given number.

Input Format

First line of input contains T - number of test cases. Its followed by T lines, each containing an integer N.

Output Format

For each test case, print the number of trailing 0s in N!, separated by new line

Here's the code for the above problem

```
`n=int(input())
 for i in range (0,n):
     num=int(input())
     count=0
     i=5
     m=num/i
     for i in range (m>=1):
          count= count+m
  print(count)`
```

the expected output is:

Input:

```
2
5
10
```

output:

```
1
2
```

but only 2 is being displayed as output overriding 1

plz help

Comment: the no. of trailing zeros in the factorial of a given number ex: 5! =120,10!=3628800

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your print statement into your outer loop:

```
result = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    num = int(input())
    count = 0
    i = 5
    m = num / i
    for i in range(m >= 1):
        i * 5
        count = count + m
    result.append(count) # <- print statement was here but I added extra indent and then changed to append
for count in result:
    print(count)
```

Per your comment, I also added code to store up your results instead of printing each result right away, so that they will all be printed at the end, after you've given all of your input.

This is one of the downsides of Python using indentation as language syntax.  It's easy to make these sorts of mistakes.

btw, this gives the output you expect, but what do you think the line **i * 5** is doing?  It isn't doing anything.  Also, with **range(m >= 1)**, you're creating a range from a boolean value, which is strange.

Comment: No, I mean OUTER loop

Comment: i tried this but the output is2
5
1
10
2 . i need it to be 2 5 10   1  2

Comment: That's because you're mixing your input and output.  I updated my answer to fix this issue.  It now stores up the output and prints it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds no. Of trailing zeroes in factorial of numbers

```
for i in range(int(input())):
     a=int(input())
     f=1
     c=0
     for j in range(1,n+1):
           f*=j
     while(f%10==0):
          f/=10
          c+=1
     print(c)
```